# Access dynamic property with "/" in name

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper to create a dynamic object from a CSV file.

The problem I have is that sometimes there are illegal characters in the name, like here:

[image]

Is there anyway that I can do a statement like:

```
if (record.Towm/Area == "foo") ...
```

Because it's dynamic I don't think I can use reflection to loop over it and check name with a string comparison.

Is there anyway I can access it through named array or some other method?

Comment: Have you tried an indexer? For example:  `record["Town/Area"]`

Comment: How do I do this to a dynamic object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an `ExpandoObject`, you should be able to get properties with an indexer like you would an [`IDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630221%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if(record["Town/Area"] == "foo")
```

Barring that, you can cast it to an `IDictionary`, and treat it as such.

```
((IDictionary<String, Object>)record)
```

Then use linq for even more overengineered goodness:

```
if( record.First(kvp => kvp.Key == "City/Town").Value == foo )
```

Comment: I forgot ExpandoObect can have named indexer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Access the columns directly using their column#, like `record.GetField(3)` or even `record.GetField("Town/Area")` etc.

Then you can compare,

```
if (String.Equals(record.GetField(3), "foo")) 
{
    //do my stuff.
}
```